# How can I replace some columns with data from an excel file?

Tags: r, excel

I have a question. Like the title said, now I need to replace some columns with new data from another single excel file. I need to replace them when certain requirements are fulfilled.

For example, I want to replace column R5 to APM (arbitrary column header names, just for example) with new data from another excel file and the following conditions should be met before replacing:

1. replace with the same ID, which means I want each person's ID to be matched when replacing
2. do not replace when a column in a row displays "N". For example, if any cell between R5 to APM in a row has an N, then do not replace it.

Basically, I want to make sure the data is exactly matched.

How can I complete this task in R? Or, how can I achieve it in MS Excel?
Many thanks in advance for your help! I will be very appreciative of each answer.

Below is an example:

[image]

Below is the text version of the screenshot:

ID                                      ID
11  2021/4/15   N   9/11/66 56.9    175 cm  Standard Test   22      N/A
11  2021/7/29   Y   9/11/66 55.7    186 cm  Standard Test   748     N/A 11  2021/7/29   Y   TWCOVID 11  1966/11/9   F   Caucasian   157 54  NO  NO

In the screenshot below, I want to replace new data with ID 11 to the row that indicates Y and to replace the old data with new data beginning from R5 and ending with APM. I can say for sure that the length of each new data is exactly the same as the length of the old data.

Comment: Sorry for some confusion in the requirement 2). In 2), I mean if any cell value between R5 to APM in a row is N, then do not replace it.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide an example of your data and what outcome you are looking for instead of describing it.

Comment: Basically, because not all information from that excel file has the same number of IDs with another file, i worry that simply replacing may cause some mismatching problems. For example, the number of person with ID 015 in the current file is 5 but in the file that I want to replace from may only have 4 of persons with ID -015. Their ID numbers are not the same. Therefore, simply replacing will cause problems.

Comment: I am confused what R5 and APM are? They are nowhere in your example dataset.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you would like to do could be achieved with the function `merge()`. Do `?merge` to obtain more information.

What is important is that the columns from your two dataframes are named the same way

Example below:

Here, you would read in both your dataset, and you would then make sure that the column names with the information that are matching are the same one dataset to the next (in your case, you want ID ("ID"), the date ("date"), and the decision on whether to merge or not ("test") to match.

```
library(readxl)
dt1 <- read_excel("path to dataset 1")
dt2 <- read_excel("path to dataset 2")
colnames(dt1)<- c("ID","date","test","DOB","weigth","height","other1","other2","other3")
colnames(dt2)<- c("ID","date","test","variable")
```

But for the sake of the example, I am recreating your two datasets:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(ID = c(11,11),
                  date = c("2021/4/15", "2021/7/29"),
                  test = c("N", "Y"),
                  DOB = c("9/11/66", "9/11/66"),
                  weight = c(56.9, 55.7),
                  heigth = c(175, 186),
                  other1 = "Standard Test",
                  other2 = c(22, 748),
                  other3 = NA)

dt2 <- data.frame(ID = 11,
                  date = "2021/7/29",
                  test = "Y",
                  variable = "TWCOVID")
```

Then, you can just merge dt1 and dt2, by specifying which columns to use (although the function would automatically recognize the columns names being the same), and specifying all.x = TRUE to say that all the rows from the dataframe x (the first one) must be preserved. Check the difference between `all` and `all.x` depending on what you want to achieve.

```
dt <- merge(x = dt1, y = dt2[dt2$test == "Y", ], by = c("ID", "date", "test"), all.x = TRUE)
```

Which gives you: (last column as the information you wanted.

[image: output dataset]

Then, export to excel:

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(dt)
```

Comment: Yes, you are understanding me correct. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Great! If this answer your question, please "accept" my answer (and vote it up, but not necessarily).